# Qual è il significato di "Ci fosse una volta che me ne va una giusta!"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa la frase "Ci fosse una volta che me ne va una giusta!"? Mi ci sono imbattuta in un esercizio d'italiano sull'uso del congiuntivo. Ho cercato su Internet, ma non ho trovato niente a riguardo. Ho pensato a qualcuno che si sta lamentando che le cose non gli vanno mai bene, ma non sono sicura che questo sia il senso della frase. Potreste farmi un esempio di qualche contesto in cui potrei usarla?

Comment: = “Non c'è nemmeno una volta in cui le cose vanno per il verso giusto (= vanno bene)”. Una costruzione simile si applica anche ad altre frasi, come per esempio “Mi stessi mai a sentire!” = “Non mi stai mai a sentire”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sì, è un'espressione comune che si usa quando una serie di cose vanno storte o quando uno ritiene di essere particolarmente sfortunato.

Il senso è :

> - se almeno una volta le cose andassero per il verso giusto.

Comment: "Se ***almeno*** una volta..."?